# Valid partition columns for external tables

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create an external table with various partition columns.

It works to do the following, for instance:

```
create or replace external table mytable( 
    myday date as to_date(substr(metadata$filename, 35, 10), 'YYYY-MM-DD'))   
    partition by (myday)
    location = @mys3stage
    file_format = (type = parquet);
```

However, I would like to use regex_substr instead of character indexing, as I won't always have consistent character indices for all partitioning columns. I would like to do this:

```
create or replace external table mytable( 
    myday date as to_date(regexp_substr(metadata$filename, 'day=[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]'), 'day=YYYY-MM-DD'))   
    partition by (myday)
    location = @mys3stage
    file_format = (type = parquet);
```

This gives me an error `Defining expression for partition column MYDAY is invalid.` I can run the `regexp_substr` clause successfully in a select statement outside of the external table creation, getting the same results as the `substr` approach.

How can I use regex string matching in my external table partition column definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`REGEX_SUBSTR` is not a function that is on the list of currently supported partition key functions.  Please use the following link to see the list of acceptable functions:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-external-table.html#partitioning-parameters

I am not completely sure I understand how your folder structure wouldn't be consistent.  Perhaps if you provided an example, this community can offer a more concise response.  However, if you are unable to come up with a parsing mechanism that works, perhaps you could leverage the `CASE` statement to handle each unique folder structure that you may come across in your environment.